# How to add a custom widget to IOS 10? (Website)

Tags: ios, websites, dashboard-widget, widgets

Is there any way to add a widget from a website to iOS? I'm not familiar with xCode, plus there's an annual fee of $99 to publish an app. Is there any way to add a widget from a website, similar to how you can add a website to your homescreen?

The Apple page about developer widgets offers no info:

> https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/widgets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't add websites to that screen on iOS.  You *can* add links to websites as icons to your iPhone, in case that helps.

Widgets are only allowed to be installed through the Apple App Store as part of an app and that developer has to specifically code the widget into their app.